# Are people who work in the same company but never actually work together called colleagues?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

colleague refers to

> a person with whom one works, especially in a profession or business.

in my company, different groups work on different projects, some of them may do not know others at all. In this scenario, are they called colleagues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say **"[a co-worker](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/co-worker)"** is the person you work together with at a company, probably in the same department or same office, someone who is working alongside you.

But someone who works in the same company but with whom you don't exactly work side-by-side is probably **"[a colleague](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/colleague)"**.

Comment: Do you have a source for that? 'Would say' and 'probably' don't sound very confident.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Hmm, Google?

Comment: I meant a source that we can see, a link. A dictionary entry would be best. Otherwise it's just your opinion. You've been here long enough to know that.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Sure, I'll try to find one. This is an answer based on just my knowledge.

Comment: Such 'answers' are deprecated.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Due to what rule?

Comment: [Answering questions](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4783/contributors-guide-to-english-language-learners/4786#4786) "Don't just give an answer, explain why and, if appropriate, include credible sources that support your answer." "answers are expected to have some sort of supporting information, which could be a link to a dictionary or Wikipedia article, or a few example usages."

Answer (score 1):

A colleague can be someone who works in the same workplace, or for the same employer, or for another employer in the same sector or industry. Also a fellow member of an body such as a political party. Associate and coworker are alternative terms.

> an associate or coworker typically in a profession or in a civil or
>   ecclesiastical office and often of similar rank or state : a fellow
>   worker or professional

[Colleague (Merriam-Webster)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/colleague)

> A person with whom one works in a profession or business.

[Colleague (Lexico/Oxford)](https://www.lexico.com/definition/colleague)

A colleague does not have to be someone who works directly with you, in the same workplace. The word can be applied more widely to people who hold similar posts, appointments, or memberships, e.g. my colleagues at Joe's Garage, in the printing industry, at the Ministry of Transport, in the Labour Party, in the legal profession, in Parliament, in judicial office, etc.